# completion/intellisense on (*args ,**kwargs) functions

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there a way to have completion/intellisense on (*args ,**kwargs) functions?

For instance:

```
class GetVar(GetVarInterface):
    @classmethod
    def fromcustom(cls,locorvar,offset=0,varType="int", name=None,deref=False,member=None):
        return GetVarCustom(locorvar,offset,varType, name,deref,member)

class GetVarCustom(GetVar):
    def __init__(self,locorvar,offset=0,varType="int", name=None,deref=False,member=None):
```

I wanted to implement this without specifying every argument of the constructor (For example using *vars, **kwargs) but didn't want to lose completion/intellisense abilities. Is there a way?

The disadvantage in the current implementation is that you would have to replicate the signature twice for every change...

Comment: IMO, replicating the signature to accommodate an IDE is a very big disadvantage. This also seems a bit twisted: why is `GetVar` providing a method to create an instance of a subclass? It's just as easy to call `GetVarCustom` directly as it is to call `GetVar.fromcustom`. (Note that your class method doesn't even use the value of `cls`, so why *is* it a class method?)

Comment: hmm, this is more of a general question. Sorry, should have been static.  I wanted to provide a single class for generating many classes that implement the interface. Anyway, It is not really the point here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution outside this site..

```
@functools.wraps(functools.partial(GetVarCustom.__init__,1))
def fromcustom(*args,**kwargs):
     return GetVarCustom(*args,**kwargs)
```

Of course, it would have been easier in case of a  standard function. However, you need to update the assigned attribute of  wraps. Otherwise it will change the function name.

```
@functools.wraps(GetVarCustom.value,assigned=['__doc__'])
def getvalue(*args,**kwargs):
     return self_custom.value(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to add a comment under the function to hint the arguments, otherwise you can't; if the ide is reading that a function has undefined arguments, it will show you that it's undefined.
A "solution" is to just use the common arguments and pass the rest as kwargs, or you can keep the original init.

```
class Single_Init:

    def __init__(self, val_a, val_b, name=None):
        self.val_a = val_a
        self.val_b = val_b
        self.name = name

class Single_Init_B(Single_Init):

    # The previous contructor is calld

    def get_result(self):
        return self.val_a + self.val_b

class Split_Const:

    def op_offset(self, offset):
        self.offset = offset

    def __init__(self, name, member=None, **kwargs):
        """ You olso can hint in a func coment """
        self.name = name
        self.member = member

        if 'offset' in kwargs:
            self.offset = kwargs['offset']
        else:
            self.offset = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    single = Single_Init_B(2, 3)
    print('Single:', single.get_result())

    split = Split_Const('Name')
    split.op_offset(0.5)
    print('Split:', split.offset)
```

Comment: I thought someone will suggest to use functools.partial. Anyway, I don't get it and it seems quite complicated.

Comment: I think partial does the trick. not sure

Comment: Do you need to have every argument to be added only in the init?, you can just initialize the variables with the default and pass them after

Comment: See my solution. There is a function for this.

Comment: On what ide does that give the correct completion?

Comment: jupyter for example.